# How to run a service without using eclipse and by using karaf?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I need to run the service outside my eclipse. I have taken my OSGi bundles as jars. I need to up the service of the bundles one by one and access the methods in it. I am trying to use Karaf to do this process. Can anyone tell me a better way to do so?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you tried and what the results were?

Comment: In my experience [Karaf tutorial from Christian Schneider](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/Karaf+Tutorials) is a good place to start with Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 0):

If you have them as osgi bundles,  why don't you just deploy them to karaf?

Comment: Actually i have only jars for each service. how can i deploy the jar in karaf?

Comment: You can use the wrap parameter to deploy standard jar file but to get the full benefit of osgi you need to either osgify your jar or use blueprint language.